# extract with regex, one liner in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to extract the word after `"="`. For `"GENEINFO=AGRN:"` in a document, I can use the regex `/GENEINFO=(.*?):/` to extract the required. However the value I wanted to returned is just `"AGRN"`. Is there a one-liner that I can use for this task?

Comment: Do you want to extract the first string between '=' and ':', as @sawa has assumed, or the first string between 'GENEINFO=' and ':', which everyone else (to date) has assumed?  Your example regex seems to suggest the latter.

Comment: If you've formed an emotional attachment to your regex, you can keep it: `"abcGENEINFO=AGRN:def"[/GENEINFO=(.*?):/].partition('=').last[0...-1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
/(?<=GENEINFO=).*?(?=:)/
```

Comment: Did we just submit identical answers at the same time?

Comment: No, mine doesn't use a capture group. ;)

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose yours is better in that regard. +1. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-match):

```
'GENEINFO=AGRN:'.match(/GENEINFO=(.*?):/)[1]
#=> "AGRN"
```

Which could also be written using the [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method:

```
'GENEINFO=AGRN:'[/GENEINFO=(.*?):/, 1]
#=> "AGRN"
```

Comment: `[]` is definitely the way to go. Cleaner regex, clear intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
"GENEINFO=AGRN:"[/(?<==).*(?=:)/]
# => "AGRN"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a lookbehind and lookahead.

```
pattern = /(?<=GENEINFO=)(.*?)(?=:)/
value = "GENEINFO=AGRN:".scan(pattern)

// [["AGRN"]]
```